# How to define a fully customized convolution neural network (CNN) in Keras?

Tags: machine-learning, keras

I am new to Keras library for machine learning and want to build a fully customized CNN network. I want to pass predefined filters (like a low pass filter) to convolution layer with adjustable weights and same goes with pooling layer. How can I do that?

Comment: This does not make sense, do you want to pass **predefined filters** or make them **adjustable**. "Weights" of the convolutional layer **are** filters.

Comment: For ex, I want to pass a low pass filter, then it should remain a LPF even after adjustment through backpropagation. Is it possible?